# How to print all the possible combinations of a N digit number without using arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations, combinatorics

I'm stressing on the point of without using an array.  Is there any mathematics derivation for this?

Comment: Array is just memory space to store data, why do you need to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "all possible combinations"?  Do you mean like an anagram of the digits?  And are you looking for just pseudocode or some specific language?

Comment: do you have an N digit number as input? may it have repeated digits?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I tag Algorithms...

Comment: @PhamTrung  how can you generate all  permutations/combinations of a number 123 without using array.Yes it is a storage DS but it provide a convenient algorithm mechanism to solve many problems because we can easily manipulate every digit with simple index mechanism.

Comment: So this question is kind of a challenge? when we solve problem, we use memory, (array is the most basic representation of memory), and you want to remove the memory part to solve problem? It is not making sense.

Comment: @PhamTrung  trying to solve it through pure mathematics..... sometime it helps to explore new ways of approaching problems..

Comment: When you say no arrays, do you mean for storing results, or none at all? For example, could we store the original number as an array of characters?

Comment: @JimWood  No we can't store it as array because using array index we can manipulate it easily but what if we have to manipulate the number directly. e.g 123 : [132,321,312,etc] but manipulation should be done on input number directly and you can store the answers in array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["Gosper's hack"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Applications) manipulating binary numbers but you are limited by the word length of the machine on the size of combinations you can generate/represent this way.

```
// find next k-combination
bool next_combination(unsigned long& x) // assume x has form x'01^a10^b in binary
{
  unsigned long u = x & -x; // extract rightmost bit 1; u =  0'00^a10^b
  unsigned long v = u + x; // set last non-trailing bit 0, and clear to the right; v=x'10^a00^b
  if (v==0) // then overflow in v, or x==0
    return false; // signal that next k-combination cannot be represented
  x = v +(((v^x)/u)>>2); // v^x = 0'11^a10^b, (v^x)/u = 0'0^b1^{a+2}, and x ← x'100^b1^a
  return true; // successful completion
}
```

Initialise `x` with the 1st `k`-combination i.e `x = (1L<<k) - 1L` (`k` `one`s are set)

What this does:

1. Uses two different representations of a combination a) as a choice and b) as a binary number
2. Uses [gray coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) (or minimal change coding) to move from one combination (binary number) to the next combination (binary number), maintaining same number of `one`s in the binary representation
3. Eventually all combinations are generated this way (but **not lexicographicaly**)

For a more *number-theoretic* representation of a combination see [Combinatorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) which represents combinations as integers, i.e a bijection from combinations to integers (if you want to use strictly artithmetic without using arrays explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

An decimal integer is essentially an array of digits. Some simple math will allow the indexing of those digits in the integer just like any other array.

The following python sample code will do exactly what you wanted by exploiting this fact:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def getNumDigits(number):
    if number == 0:
        digits = 1
    else:
        digits = 0
        while number > 0:
            digits += 1
            number //= 10
    return digits

def getDigitAtPosition(position, number):
    return (number // (10**position)) % 10

def swapDigits(number, position_one, position_two):
    digit_one = getDigitAtPosition(position_one, number)
    digit_two = getDigitAtPosition(position_two, number)
    difference = digit_one - digit_two
    return number + (difference * 10**position_two) - (difference * 10**position_one)

def sortNumber(number, num_digits=None):
    if num_digits is None:
        num_digits = getNumDigits(number)
    for i in range(num_digits-1):
        for j in range(i+1, num_digits):
            if getDigitAtPosition(j, number) < getDigitAtPosition(i, number):
                number = swapDigits(number, i, j)
    return number

def isDigitInNumber(digit, number):
    for i in range(getNumDigits(number)):
        if getDigitAtPosition(i, number) == digit:
            return True
    return False

def printCombinations_sorted(number, prepend, num_digits):
    if num_digits == 1:
        print(number + (prepend * (10**num_digits)))
    else:
        lead_position = num_digits-1
        lead_digit = getDigitAtPosition(lead_position, number)
        digits_swapped = lead_digit
        printCombinations_sorted(number % 10**(lead_position), (prepend*10) + lead_digit, num_digits-1)
        for i in range(num_digits-1):
            sub_number = swapDigits(number, num_digits-1, num_digits-2-i)
            sub_lead_digit = getDigitAtPosition(lead_position, sub_number)
            if not isDigitInNumber(sub_lead_digit, digits_swapped):
                digits_swapped = digits_swapped*10 + sub_lead_digit
                printCombinations_sorted(sub_number % 10**(lead_position), (prepend*10) + sub_lead_digit, num_digits-1)

def printCombinations(number):
    num_digits = getNumDigits(number)
    number = sortNumber(number, num_digits)
    printCombinations_sorted(number, 0, num_digits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    number = 101010
    printCombinations(number)
```

Since it was not specified if repeated digits would be allowed, I wrote this with the assumption that they would. It could be simplified quite a bit if that is not the case.