# Calculate betting odds in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a script, that would automatically calculate betting odds ratio of teams by some given index (the higher, the better the team is and the probability to win is higher) from a mysql table.

For example:

Team 1 - index 351
Team 2 - index 152
Team 3 - index 400
Team 4 - index 120

So, team 3 should have the lowest odd ratio (f.e. 2,7:1) - highest probability to win and team 4 the highest ratio (f.e. 30:1).

The script should

1. detect how many teams are in the game
2. calculate odds by the given index for each team

Thanks for all ideas!

Edit: I'm not asking for coding service, I just couldn't figure out the theory.
And, it was actually much easier than I thought.

```
$id = 9;

$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id='".$id."'");

$sum = 0;

while($f1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1))
{$sum = $sum + $f1['index'];}


$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id='".$id."'");
while($f2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2))
{
$p = $f2['index'] / $sum;
$l = 1/$p;
echo "team ".$f2['team_id']." - "; echo round($l, 2); echo"<br>";
}
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Add your code to start with.

Comment: a lot of coding writing service happens here :>

Comment: you have to look into statistics concepts, the code is not so much the issue as the statistics computations involved (depending on the criteria of course), see [ranked statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking)

Comment: No code writing is not happening, examples may be given or corrections to existing code. People here do not write code for you (or do your homeworks)

Comment: i can point you 2M answers then

Comment: @Drew Pierce you are correct. lot of coding writing services happen. even some time users just post only text data and lot of answer comes for them.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh and Drew, in that case i do not do that. Knowledge is seeked and earned. If one is not interested in this, there is no point answering or providing sample codes, better hire someone that does this job

Comment: world is big and my friend people didn't think in your way. Look below. You will get what happen. either code provided without asking code or comment written as an answer.

Comment: ok @NikosM. You don't do that. btw what were you thinking 5 hours ago with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684360/how-to-print-all-the-possible-combinations-of-a-n-digit-number-without-using-arr/

Comment: @DrewPierce, look closer and you will see my answer there is consistent with what i type here

Comment: @everyone: jesus people, don't flame. Make your point by casting your vote, that's all.

Comment: no flaming just being real

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to add the indexes and divide each by the sum. In your example, the sum is 1023 so each one gets index/1023. This will give you the probability p of each event. Your betting odds then are 1/p

(no code because this is not a coding service, unless you provide some code yourself to start with :P)